# Unexpected behaviour of Matlab abstract subclass

Tags: matlab, oop, abstract-class

I am writing some Matlab code to load data from specific file formats such that I can treat the loaded data in a uniform way.

I therefore want to represent the data using an abstract class with unique subclasses for each possible file format.

Central to my scheme is a method that either gets the data from file (the unique bit of the implementation) or, if the data was already loaded, just spits it out. I.e. a sort of lazy loading system since getting data from disk can be slow...

I wanted to setup an abstract class in my Matlab program like so:

```
classdef TCSPCImageData

properties (SetAccess = protected)
    % The same for all subclasses.
    frameindex = -1;
    framedata = '';
    ...
end

properties (Abstract, SetAccess = protected)

    % Needs to be set by subclass
    type
end

methods
    % Constructor. Code omitted for brevity
    function obj = TCSPCImageData(path)
        ...
    end

    function data = frame(obj, idx, tshift)
        % Some shared functionality.
        if (obj.frameindex == idx)
            ...
        else
            % Call a specific subclass method.
            data = obj.getframe(idx,tshift);
        end
    end

end

methods (Abstract, Access = protected)
    % The abstract method that will be implemented by each subclass.
    getframe(obj, idx, tshift)
end
end
```

So in summary, there is a method in my superclass with functionality that all subclasses should share but in that method I call a specific implementation, unique to each subclass.

Then a subclass looks like this:

```
classdef PTUImageData < Data.TCSPCImageData

properties (SetAccess = protected)

    % Specific initialisation of this variable
    type = 'PTU';

end

methods

    % We call the superclass constructor.
    function obj = PTUImageData(path)

        obj@Data.TCSPCImageData(path);

    end

    % Apparently, you need to call the superclass method.
    function data = frame(obj, idx, tshift)
        data = frame@Data.TCSPCImageData(obj, idx, tshift);
    end

end

methods(Access = protected)

    % The specific implementation.
    function data = getframe(obj, idx, tshift)

        obj.framedata = 'some value';

    end

end
end
```

Naively, I thought this should work nicely.

However, `obj.framedata = 'some value';` only updates the variable in the scope of the subclass. The value is not maintained when running this code like so:

```
testdata = Data.PTUImageData('somepath');
testdata.frame(1,1);
```

Setting a breakpoint inside the subclass shows that `obj.framedata` gets set but if I check my testdata object later on, testdata.framedata will be empty, which is totally unexpected.

Who can show me the error of my ways?

**EDIT**

As remarked in the answer below, there is no need to explicitly call the `frame` function:

```
classdef PTUImageData < Data.TCSPCImageData

    properties (SetAccess = protected)

        % Specific initialisation of this variable
        type = 'PTU';

    end

    methods

        % We call the superclass constructor.
        function obj = PTUImageData(path)

        obj@Data.TCSPCImageData(path);

        end

    end

    methods(Access = protected)

    % The specific implementation.
    function data = getframe(obj, idx, tshift)

        obj.framedata = 'some value';

    end

end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `TCSPCImageData` a *handle* class, by inheriting from `handle`:

```
classdef TCSPCImageData < handle
```

Look in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-objects.html) for more information about handle classes.

The default is for a class to be a *value* class, which means that it will have *pass-by-value* behaviour. In other words, they will behave like regular numeric arrays:

```
>> a = 2;
>> b = a;
>> a = 3;
>> b
b = 
    2
```

Note that `b` has not changed when you changed `a`, because `b` is a *copy* of `a`, not a reference to `a` itself. They have pass-by-value behaviour.

On the other hand, some other variables (such as MATLAB graphics variables) are *handle* variables, and have *pass-by-reference* behaviour:

```
>> a = figure;
>> get(a,'Name')
ans =
     ''
>> b = a;
>> get(b,'Name')
ans =
     ''
>> set(a,'Name', 'hello')
>> get(b,'Name')
ans =
hello
```

Note that the property of `b` changed when you changed the property of `a`, because `b` is a reference to `a`, rather than a copy of it. They have pass-by-reference behaviour.

By default, MATLAB classes have value behaviour. You give them handle behaviour by inheriting from `handle`.

PS I'm pretty sure you shouldn't need to implement the method `frame` within the subclass `PTUImageData`; it should just inherit the implementation from `TCSPCImageData`.

Comment: *the sound of a penny dropping* To think that I am actually aware of By Value and By Ref because that is also relevant to C# :-/ I guess I was just too weirded our by the funny Matlab syntax. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also of note: matlab doesn't seem to like it when you just add < handle to your code file. You might get "The class 'handle' is not a superclass of class ..." errors. In that case just give it a "clear" and "clear classes". After that, it will work flawlessly.

Comment: And you were also right about the "frame" function. It gets inherited automatically, which only seems logical...

Comment: On the topic of `clear`: yes, when you have variables of a class existing in a workspace and you change the class definition, the change won't get applied until you delete those variables - you'll get some sort of warning if you try to use them. `clear` will typically work by deleting most things; but `clear classes` explicitly forces all class definitions to be updated.